# How to extract record's table name when using Table wildcard functions

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to extract any of the TABLE metadata into the SELECT statement itself?  For instance, I'd like to know the first time some data showed up in a dataset.  I've seen another post ([How to get table name when using TABLE_DATE_RANGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123877/how-to-get-table-name-when-using-table-date-range)) that discusses getting table names, but really what I need is the table name associated with each piece of data.  This dataset has table names that are partitioned by day so names of tables look like this; "201507010000", "201507020000", etc.  I'd like to do something like the following:

```
SELECT
    foo,
    __TABLE__.table_id as table_id
FROM TABLE_QUERY([project:dataset], 'true')
ORDER BY table_id
```

Comment: How can you select stuff with a from clause from a table you didn't name?

Comment: TABLE_QUERY will scan all tables within the identified dataset.  If TABLE_QUERY is able to scan all tables in that dataset, it should be able to get metadata like table name.  That is what I am looking for, the ability to get the table name of each table within that dataset corresponding to the data.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much the same request, ie having the ability to extract table_id name from the table meta data within the query.  There is a bug/feature request for this support.  Please add your vote if this is something any of you would like to see, [163](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=163)